# How to set up Password Reset User Flow in B2C to avoid email address of non-ad users

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an issue using Azure B2C for password reset. The issue occurs after entering an email that has not been signed up, and verifying the numerical code.

Hitting 'Continue' a few times causes our site to behave unexpectedly.

[image: password reset page in question]

Very new to B2C -- We've got a B2C_ResetPassword.xml in our solution, but not sure what would control this aspect. What can I do?

Comment: Hi @Benny. What do you expect the page behavior to be?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett -- I would expect that 'Continue' shouldn't be clickable in the case of an error like this. Doesn't seem to make sense that people can just click continue with the Reset Password workflow when their account doesn't exist in the system

Answer (score 0):

You mean of unexpected behavior is "B2C policy redirecting to your redirect URI along with exception message or something else?

In case of redirect URI exception message, it's application who can handle that exception gracefully.

Try to capture the exception code in your app and show meaningful error message.